Record-Trigger Flow on EventRelation, workaround for lack of support?
Record-Trigger flows do not allow selection of the EventRelation object.  I'm trying to figure out the best workaround, zero code would be optimal, low code is not desired but may be the only solution.
The one way I figured it could be done is to put Change Data Capture on EventRelation.  But I searched for articles on CDC and found some from the 2021 timeframe stating that CDC cannot be directly handled by flow.  That means that at least a bit of Apex code would have to be written to handle the CDC via a trigger and then have that invoke a flow.  That may be it; the only way to do it.  But I'm wondering if anything has changed since those 2021 articles that might provide a no-code instead of a low-code solution.
What I want to do, is put code in a package that will update the status and response in EventRelation records.  The subscriber of the package might then have specific requirements for downstream processing, like send email, perform other updates, etc.  I'd rather not have to write code to anticipate handling many possible user requirements and scenarios.  I'd rather say to the subscriber of the package "Write a flow on this condition to do whatever you need done."

What are you trying to accomplish? See XY Problem. (Please edit your question).
